# summing notation in CSS between CSS classes (.class1 + .class2)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I think I couldn't find the purposive searching term(s) for web so I needed to ask here.

Sometimes I see CSS statements like this:

`.class1 {...}`

`.class2 {...}`

`.class1 + .class2 {...}`

**Q1)** What does CSS understands if there are 3 CSS statements like above?

**Q2)** I tried to find clue on http://jsbin.com/detuxema/1/edit but it didn't help. May you please provide a mini-example

Comment: used to this http://jsbin.com/detuxema/4/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out http://jsbin.com/detuxema/2/edit

In this example,

you have a `<p>` element with class `class1` and class `class2` and another `<p>` element with class `class2`.

for the first `<p>` element the first 2 rules will be applied because it has both classes in the `class` attribute

the 3rd rule will be applied to only the 2nd `<p>` element because that rule is only applied to immediate sibling

Here's some more info about sibling selectors

http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors

Answer (score 3):

Rule

```
.class1 + .class2 {
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

takes effect on `.class2` only is previous sibling is `.class1`. Take a look at this comprehensive demonstration of all three situations **http://jsfiddle.net/PzGb9/**.

Comment: +1 for `sibling` term. by the help of your answer, I learnt that complete term was `Adjacent sibling selectors`. [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors]